# Solr Highlighting - Display Snippet

Tags: solr, code-snippets, highlighting, nutch, solr4

I have successfully set up highlighting in Solr4, I am indexing docx, xlsx & pdf's mainly so just have fields like url, title & content.

I have Solr highlighting the content field and it displays the small snippet of text, but sometimes the matched word is in the title as opposed to the content and therefore it will not return me a snippet of text

Is there any way of returning even just the first line or two from the content field so that it is not left blank.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your query URL looks like `q=(title:ABC OR content:ABC)&hl=true&hl.fl=title,content`

Try adding [`hl.alternateField`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.alternateField)`=content` to the query

Answer (score 0):

Use `fl=content` parameter with your query. If no highlighted **content** returned then generate snippet from **content (fl=content)** field returned with each document in result set.

Comment: That would work i guess but the content field is very large and would also need some more complex coding.  I was hoping there was a way that the highlighting setting would allow for it